# Even if no errors on Compilation and Runtime, Program output is not as expected

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcheckbox, itemlistener

A Java Swing applet which includes 3 Checkboxes and a TextField. The specified checkbox when clicked displays title assigned to the corresponding checkbox in the given TextField. The problem is that even if no errors on Compilation and Runtime, a blank frame is shown as output..!!

here is the Java code :

SwingAll class :

```
package swingall;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class SwingAll extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

JTextField t1;
JCheckBox c1,c2,c3;

public void init()
{
    Container cp=getContentPane();
    t1=new JTextField(20);
    c1=new JCheckBox("Arts");
    c2=new JCheckBox("Commerce");
    c3=new JCheckBox("Science");
    add(c1);
    add(c2);
    add(c3);
    add(t1);
    c1.addItemListener(this);
    c2.addItemListener(this);
    c3.addItemListener(this);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource()==c1)
    {
        t1.setText("Arts");
    }
    if (e.getSource()==c2)
    {
        t1.setText("Commerce");
    }
    if (e.getSource()==c3)
    {
        t1.setText("Science");
    }
}
}
```

The Main Class is :

```
package swingall;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingAll sg=new swingAll();
    sg.setSize(500, 500);
    sg.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Which part of your code do you expect to prevent that?

Comment: Even if it compiles and runs, code does what you tell it to do, not what you *think* you're telling it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called your `init()` method.

Therefore, you never put anything into the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You dont call your init-method.
Add a constructor

```
public SwingAll () {
   init();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make your class init() to constructor which it should be SwingAll
try adding `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`
i don't see a title for the window try setting

```
super("window name");
```

and

```
 setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, `init()` was not being called.  OTOH, when it is, only one component is displayed.  This variant fixes both problems.

[image: Example GUI]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingAll extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

JTextField t1;
JCheckBox c1,c2,c3;

public void init()
{
    // end the JVM when frame is closed.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Container cp=getContentPane();
    // set a layout that takes many components without a 
    // constraint and displays them.
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    t1=new JTextField(20);
    c1=new JCheckBox("Arts");
    c2=new JCheckBox("Commerce");
    c3=new JCheckBox("Science");
    add(c1);
    add(c2);
    add(c3);
    add(t1);
    c1.addItemListener(this);
    c2.addItemListener(this);
    c3.addItemListener(this);
    // pack the GUI to the size needed to display the content
    pack();
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource()==c1)
    {
        t1.setText("Arts");
    }
    if (e.getSource()==c3)
    {
        t1.setText("Commerce");
    }
    if (e.getSource()==c3)
    {
        t1.setText("Science");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // should be started on the EDT.
    SwingAll sg= new SwingAll();
    sg.init();
    sg.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

### Other tips

1. `// should be started on the EDT.`  Swing GUIs should be started and updated on the Event Dispatch Thread - left as an exercise for the user.
2. The default layout of a frame is `BorderLayout`.  This layout has 5 possible areas that can be specified by constraints, each of which can hold exactly one component.  By adding the components to the border layout without constraints, they all defaulted to `BorderLayout.CENTER`.
3. Don't set the size of the GUI, simply call `pack()` after the components are added.
4. If those check-boxes should be 'one only at a time', look to `JRadioButton` and `ButtonGroup`.

Comment: cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); that's what I forgot to give and also I didn't called init() as you mentioned earlier.....thanks a lot Sir....java is challenging always....!! done...output is shown as mentioned above...!!